# How to shrink my expression with a ternary operator

Tags: java, android

I would love to know how to shrink this code into 1 line with a ternator operator, the idea is change the drawable of a image inside my RecyclerView when its 1 or 0, I have done this but I think is not that performant to have multiple if elses to do it, instead I know that it can be done in just 1 line with a ternary operator.

```
 if(json.hasTime(mArrayList.get(mPosition))==1){
                    mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_event_black_24dp);
                }else{
                    mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_event_busy_black_24dp);
                }
```

I want to do something like this :

```
(if 1 or 0 ? value 1 : value2 );
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  You risk serious maintainability issues with unnecessary optimizations like this.

Comment: Its more efficient for me to shrink the operation in one line because I need to do the same for a few more images, instead of having a chained if statment I need to implement it like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
 mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(json.hasTime(mArrayList.get(mPosition))==1 ? R.drawable.ic_event_black_24dp : R.drawable.ic_event_busy_black_24dp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always convert expressions from (1) to (2) like so,

```
//(1)
if(condition){
    stmt1;
}else{
    stmt2;
}

//(2)
somevariable = condition?stmt1:stmt2;
```

So your single line expression can be written as follows,

```
mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(json.hasTime(mArrayList.get(mPosition))==1?R.drawable.ic_event_black_24dp:R.drawable.ic_event_busy_black_24dp);
```

Comment: This code won't compile, since it's not a statement. You must have an assignment for it to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(json.hasTime(mArrayList.get(mPosition))==1? 
                               R.drawable.ic_event_black_24dp : R.drawable.ic_event_busy_black_24dp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    json.tieneHora(mArrayList.get(mPosition))==1?mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_event_black_24dp):mHolder.imageEvent.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_event_busy_black_24dp);
```